# Bind a generic list to a listbox and also use a datatemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm trying to implement something quite simple but I'm on my first steps in WPF and I'm having some problems. I have a class called Component which has a property called Vertices. Vertices is a generic List of type Point. What I want is to bind the vertices property to a listbox. This is easy by using this code in my XAML in the listbox declaration:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Component.Vertices, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource verticesconverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The tricky part is when I try to create a datatemplate for the listbox. I want each row of the listbox to display a textbox with the values of the Vertex (Point.X, Point.Y) and a button to allow me to delete the item. Could you help me on the datatemplate definition. The code below doesn't work to bind the X,Y values into two separate textboxes. Could you point me on the mistake and why nothing is displayed in the textboxes?

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Component.Vertices, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
             <TextBox Text="{Binding X}" MinWidth="35" MaxWidth="35"/>
             <TextBox Text="{Binding Y}" MinWidth="35" MaxWidth="35"/>
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    /ListBox>
```

Comment: Please give me some code-behind for you class and the collection, maybe that is the problem, also show me where you set the DataContext if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<ListBox ... Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
          <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Children>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding X}" Margin="5"/>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Y}" Margin="5"/>
          <Button Grid.Column="2" Tag="{Binding}" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click" Content="Remove"/>
        </Grid.Children>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button senderB = (Button)sender;
  Point pt = (Point)senderB.Tag;
  Collection.Remove(pt);
}
```

Note: Your list in the GUI will not get updated unless your bound collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (Standard-implementation you can use: `ObservableCollection<T>`)

Edit: Common binding-fail causes:
1. Bound source is not a public property -> make it one
2. Binding path is not absolute and there is no DataContext to start from
-> Set DataContext of your window in the constructor to itself (`this`) or...
-> Set ElementName in the Binding to the name of your window if that is where your property is

Edit2: If your collection consists of Vertices and if your `Vertex` class contains a point with the property-name `Point` you need to change the bindings to `{Binding Point.X}` and `{Binding Point.Y}`, post more code next time please.

Comment: I used the exact code above and it doesn't display anything. Should I keep my previous code for the ListBox ItemSource binding or i need to make changes there? (I removed the converter to test your code of course)

Comment: You should keep your previous binding (which should just bind the collection, what did the converter do?), the binding should go straight to the collection of Points, so that the DataContext in the DataTemplate is a point (enabling the access of the coordinates via {Binding X}, to debug binding errors check the output window (View -> Output in VS2010)